# Parsing a list of strings and enumerate them based on line number

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, filtering, string-comparison

Can someone help me take a list of strings and enumerate string values based on line number?

Im trying to figure out how to parse all my known favorite network SSIDs and then assign each SSID a number based on the order from the output. Example:

If I run networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0 (on macOS), I get the following output based on my recent Wi-Fi favorites list (Apple calls this the 'Preferred Network' list):

```
Preferred networks on en0:
Denny's
Hilton Hotel 2465
Hipster Cafe
My_Moms_Basement
Airport_bar
Marriot - Public-5G
OFFICE
```

I want to parse this output above, search/filter for my corporate SSID ("OFFICE" in this example) and then get its line number (in this case "OFFICE" is listed on line 8 -  if you count the header "Preferred networks on en0:").

Ultimately I want to determine if SSID "OFFICE" is at the top of the list or not, and if it's NOT then I'll use the networksetup command to move it to the top - But I only want to take action if SSID "OFFICE" is not already at the top. Apple considers the top line “index 0” in this context (so line/array counting technically starts with 0,1,2,3 etc).

I have tried wc, sort, and various counting loops but I cant seem to get this to give me the output I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign an index to every line of your file, you could use an array (declare -a in bash)

Assuming the lines you mentioned are in a file named "preferred_networks", you could write this to create the array (one entry of the array for every line) :

```
declare -a ssid
exec 5<./preferred_networks 
((i=0))
while read line<&5; do 
    ssid[i]=$line
    ((++i))
done
```

Then you could read your array (containing $i elements) with the following loop:

```
for j in `seq 0 $i` ; do
 echo ssid[$j]
done
```